# imtransform with inf as FillValues

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a code that preform a translation of an image by an offset in X axis.
I want to make that when the image goes out of bounds the intensity value will be inf.

So I preform such code.

```
t = maketform('affine',[1 0 ; 0 1; -offset 0]);
origbounds = [1 1; H W];
Im2 = imtransform(Img,t,'XData',origbounds(:,2)','YData',origbounds(:,1)', 'FillValues', inf);
```

and I get the first *row* of Im2 full of NaN .

I just want that when offset is greater then width of Img fill the last *column* with inf.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing an [interpolation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html#inputarg_interp) artifact. Try using "nearest" neighbor interpolation instead of the default "bilinear".

Example:

```
interpMethod = 'nearest';    %# 'bicubic', 'bilinear', 'nearest'
fillval = Inf;               %# Inf, Nan, 0.9

offset = 20;
img = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
t = eye(3,2); t(3,1) = -offset;
img2 = imtransform(img, maketform('affine',t), interpMethod, ...
    'FillValues',fillval, 'XData',[1 size(img,2)], 'YData',[1 size(img,1)]);
subplot(211), imshow(img)
subplot(212), imshow(img2)
```

[image]